# Recommended VPN approach for SOHO

Tags: vpn, vps, openvpn

I need to implement a VPN solution in a SOHO environment. So far I know of several alternatives:

-Hire a VPN provider

-VPS with OpenVPN.

-Run a dd-wrt OpenVPN enabled router.

I'm searching for a hosted alternative if possible, but I don't have enough knowledge to ensure a secure VPS setup.
I'm also looking for VPN out-of-the-box providers, but I think most of them are not reliable, in terms of privacy.
Last option is pretty cool, but It would require static IP and hiring a domain, so I think it would be worth looking for a VPS and forget about maintenance.
Hamachi-like options are discarded.

Which one would be the recommended approach and why?
Thanks.

Comment: dd-wrt VPN (or similar solutions) doesn't need a static IP address or a domain, you can just use a DynDNS service. I am doing this for years at home and with a few small client offices.

Comment: +1. I'd vote up, but I don't have enough reputation yet XD. Very useful for the HO part of SOHO.

Comment: @SvenW by the way, is DynDNS configurable in dd-wrt, or linux linksys routers (I'm thinking on WRT54GL, for instance) with default firmware?

Comment: I am not sure about the default WRT54GL firmware, but dd-wrt/OpenWRT surely offer DynDNS modules, and I've seen it in stock firmware on more and more other devices.

Comment: of course there is no strictly *technical* need for a static IP address at the VPN server side. But if you are the one to troubleshoot connectivity problems and are not on site, it helps a lot with diagnosing.

Answer (score 0):

The major telco carriers (AT&T, Verizon, etc.) offer managed VPN solutions. You might take a look to see if their offerings fit your requirements.